# jQuery window width in math calculations issue

Tags: jquery

Hi i have a simple calculation which theoretically should work... But it doesn't, namely I have this:

```
    var win_width = $(window).width();
    var qc_widht  = 100;
    var container = 900;
    var a = win_width - container;
    var b = win_width - a - qc_widht;

    console.log(a + ' ' + b + ' ' +win_width);
```

And i use it in window.on('resize') function.

When i check the log both a and win_width change but b stays the same (never changes. My question is why b never changes?

Great thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Raf

Comment: no. i'm not. copy the code and see for yourself

Comment: Anyway, when adding and subtracting the same amounts on both sides of an equation, you end up with the same result

Comment: Not that javascript cares, but you misspelled "width" in your `qc_widht` variable.

Comment: To put it simpler, look at your logs, it's clear that `a` increases the same amount as `win_width` decreases, this is just a math issue

Comment: adeneo. When resizing window var a changes, so should var b

Comment: No, when resizing the window, `a` changes because the window changes, but you counteract that change in `b` by once again adding the windows width. When you subtract it one place, and add it back another place, you get .... the exact same thing

Comment: Your math is off. Use algebra to find the value of `container` using your  `var a = win_width - container;`. The answer is `container = win_width - a`. So, if you substitute that in your `b` calculation, you're literally saying `var b = container - qc_width`. It will **always** be 800.

Comment: I see it now. yes i got it all wrong

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zd0bff0o/

Comment: thanks guys for pointing out the error to me. can't believe it was such a simple mistake. I must be working too long today.